# React create element props is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I have a generic ListComponent function

```
function ListComponent() {
    return React.createElement(
      "ul",
      { className: "list" },
      items.map((item, i) => React.createElement("li", {key: i}, item))
    );
  }
```

Now I want to pass an array to that component as props and render it:

```
const vacations = ["Spain", "Greece", "Vietnam"];
const VacationsList = React.createElement(ListComponent, {items: vacations}, null);

ReactDOM.render(VacationsList, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I am getting the ReferenceError "items is not defined". How can I fix this?

Comment: You aren't declaring the props in `ListComponent`'s parameter list. You need `function ListComponent({items})` if you want to receive an `items` prop (or just `function ListComponent(props)` and use `props.items`, but destructuring is really common in component parameter lists).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to recieve the items like

```js
function ListComponent({ items }) {
    return React.createElement(
      "ul",
      { className: "list" },
      items.map((item, i) => React.createElement("li", {key: i}, item))
    );
  }
```